# Discord.py bot events formatted exactly the same yet one runs and one won't run

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I've recently been experimenting with discord bots and the discord API, but I have come to a problem with bot events.  When made two events using the discord.py module, only one would work while the other one did not, yet both were formatted exactly the same.  Why is this happening and how can I fix this problem?  Here is my code:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    message = await bot.wait_for_message(author=message.author)
    if message.content.startswith('!genlifetime password'):
        global amount
        amount = message.content[len('!genlifetime password'):].strip()
        num = int(amount)
        chars = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0']
        for x in range(0, num):
            authkey1 = ''
            authkey2 = ''
            authkey3 = ''
            authkey4 = ''
            for i in range(0,4):
                authkey1 = authkey1 + chars[random.randrange(0,35)]
            for i in range(0,4):
                authkey2 = authkey2 + chars[random.randrange(0,35)]
            for i in range(0,4):
                authkey3 = authkey3 + chars[random.randrange(0,35)]
            for i in range(0,4):
                authkey4 = authkey4 + chars[random.randrange(0,35)]
            authkey = authkey1 + '-' + authkey2 + '-' + authkey3 + '-' + authkey4
            print(authkey)
            with open(keyfile, 'a') as f:
                f.write(authkey + ' LIFETIME \n')

@bot.event
async def authorize(message):
    message = await bot.wait_for_message(author=message.author)
    if message.content.startswith('!activate'):
        global key
        key = message.content[len('!activate'):].strip()
        print(key)        

bot.run("NTM3Mzk1NDQzNzAxNjQ1MzEz.DykoDA.x5PrEwxZ0hlY2TeCtKVlg1QsbfQ")
```

When I run my bot and type in `!genlifetime password 10`, the bot will generate 10 keys like it is supposed to, print them in the shell, and put them in keys.txt.  However, the `authorize` event does not work at all.  If I type in !authorize key nothing happens in the shell.  The key is not printed at all.  I even tried putting a print before the `message = await bot.wait_for_message(author=message.author)` but that print would not print out either.  Both events are formatted the same way, so why does one work while the other does not?

Comment: If you change the order of the functions in the file so that `authorize()` appears first, does it execute?

Comment: @varlogtim No, same result occurs where the generate key one works and the authenticate does not.

Comment: Is it as simple as "!authorize" vs "!activate"?

Comment: @CraigMeier that doesn’t work either.

Comment: Link to API docs: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html - this mentions the `on_message()` function but not any `authorize()` function

Comment: You need to use the `commands` extension: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am thinking that the code should maybe look like this:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    message = await bot.wait_for_message(author=message.author)
    if message.content.startswith('!activate'):
        global key
        key = message.content[len('!activate'):].strip()
        print(key)        
    if message.content.startswith('!genlifetime password'):
        global amount
        amount = message.content[len('!genlifetime password'):].strip()
        num = int(amount)
        chars = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0']
        for x in range(0, num):
            authkey1 = ''
            authkey2 = ''
            authkey3 = ''
            authkey4 = ''
            for i in range(0,4):
                authkey1 = authkey1 + chars[random.randrange(0,35)]
            for i in range(0,4):
                authkey2 = authkey2 + chars[random.randrange(0,35)]
            for i in range(0,4):
                authkey3 = authkey3 + chars[random.randrange(0,35)]
            for i in range(0,4):
                authkey4 = authkey4 + chars[random.randrange(0,35)]
            authkey = authkey1 + '-' + authkey2 + '-' + authkey3 + '-' + authkey4
            print(authkey)
            with open(keyfile, 'a') as f:
                f.write(authkey + ' LIFETIME \n')
```

Although, I haven't tested this.

Comment: Although, if that does work, I would probably abstract that further and have a `on_message()` function which handles reading messages and then each separate function that actually does the work, e.g., the `gen_password()` and `activate()` functions

Comment: Cool cool! You should probably split the message handling and other logic as I mentioned because this will get super message as you expand functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, will definitely do this!

Answer (score 0):

The `wait_for_message` calls seem superfluous: according to the docs, the `message` argument passed into the callbacks is the message you want. If you were to remove the calls to `wait_for_message` and just use the message passed in directly, it would probably work as expected.